# Complex Jira Query with join

Tags: jira, jql

Assume I have a project called "alpha". I want to create a query in Jira which

Searches for all epics from project alpha where the state is not in (Backlog, Closed, Invalid) where either no child issues are existing or (if child stories are existing) for the child issue the following criteria **are not** fullfilled

- state is not in (Backlog, Closed, Invalid)
- project is also alpha
- a sprint is assigned to the issue

I am able to do the query for the epics and for the stories but I dont get the connections. It is like a join in sql but my knowledge about JQl here comes to the edge.

edit: ScritpRunner is installed

Answer (score 1):

You can create two filters :

1- Filter for the query for the stories named "**Your_Story_Filter_Name**" :
status not in (Backlog, Closed, Invalid) and project = "alpha" and Sprint is not EMPTY

2- Filter for the query for the epics named "**Your_Epic_Filter_Name**" :
issuetype = Epic and project = "alpha" and status not in (Backlog, Closed, Invalid)

Now you can use the connection between the queries by using the JQL below :

**filter = Your_Epic_Filter_Name and (issueFunction not in hasLinkType("Epic-Story Link") or issueFunction in epicsOf("filter = Your_Story_Filter_Name"))**

This helps you to get a list of epics that match all their requirements and that their issues match all their requirements also.